# How to set process env variables in config fle in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I need to set some common global variables in one config file and will get those values where required using Node.js. Here I need to implement `process.env`. My code is below:

```
var port=8989;
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var session = require('express-session');
var multer  = require('multer')
var app=module.exports=express();
var server=http.Server(app);
var admin=require('./route/route.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
app.use(session({secret: 'FGDPlexel',resave: true,saveUninitialized: true}));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
var storage =multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server is running on the port"+port);
```

Here I am assigning `port=8989` but here I need to create one config file and will assign all variable there. In this `server.js` that file will include and user will get the required values.

Comment: What about `dotenv`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv ?

Comment: I have not implemented. Can you say this can be implement in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm package. It requires you to setup an `.env` file with key-value pairs in the format `KEY=VALUE` like `SECRET_KEY=MEGASECRETKEY`.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.load({
    path: '.env.globals' // example
});
```

and you can access your variables like `process.env.SECRET_KEY`

Comment: I am little bit confused here. Let me to explain my understanding on your solution. I will include above in my server.js file and will get the values like `process.env.SECRET_KEY`. I have to create one `.env` file like `e.g-config.env` .Here i need to know how can I assign the values to the respective key and how that file will include inside the server file.

Comment: With `dotenv.load({path: '.env.globals' // example});` the respective keys will be read from the file and assigned to your `process.env` global object. By using `path:...` the server file will load your variables. You can use in your file `PORT=3000` for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear for me what you are specifically asking for, but for configuration purposes, you can create your own config.js file and require it.

For instance;

```
var settings = {
    port: process.env.PORT
};

module.exports = settings;
```

Then at your server.js, you can require this file.

```
var settings = require('./config.js');
```

Comment: `process.env.PORT = settings.port;` line will included inside `config.js` file right ? Actually here I need to write `port=process.env.PORT` instead of `port=8989`.

Comment: @satya: Edited my answer to solve your problem about configuration. Check out, please.

Comment: @ Volem : then where is the port number `i.e-8989`. That need to set also.

Comment: It is as it mentions, environment variable. Search google for setting environment variable in Linux/Windows or whatever you use